# How to sum count data filter by date in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

need help I got stuck in a week.
I have this conditions
List of polis number, and approval date.
I wanna know count of per polis and have condition if count 3= 3 times, 4=4 times ,5=5 times and >5 more than 5 times, but filter by date.
In the end I will show the result as a bar chat.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Show your sample raw data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new **SUMMARIZE** table from your base table as below-

```
summarize_table = 
SUMMARIZE
(
    your_table_name,
    your_table_name[approval date],
    your_table_name[polis no],
    "count",COUNT(your_table_name[polis no]),
    "count_details", 
        SWITCH(
            COUNT(your_table_name[polis no]),
            1, "1 Times",
            2, "2 Times",
            3, "3 Times",
            4, "4 Times",
            5, "5 Times",
            ">5 Times"
        )
)
```

**Now** create your bar chart from the new table **summarize_table** and the output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: I tried use same function, but get error
“The expressio refers to multiple coulmns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.

Comment: The data exactly same like example

Comment: Dynamic countable = var minDate=calculate(min(query2[aprv_1])) var x =calculate(count(query2[rgpynum]), filter ((query2),query2[polis_no]<=max (query2[polis_no])&& query2[aprv_1]<=lastdate((calender[date_filter]) && query2[aprv_1] >=firstdate((calender[date_filter]) )) return if(x=3, “3 times”,if (x=4,”4 times”,if(x=5,”5 Times”, if(x>5,”>5 Times”))))